# Output to a sequence add a newline when working with map objects

Tags: kubernetes, range, sequence, kubernetes-helm

I want to create several Service definitions using a defined range on my values.yaml file.

values.yaml

```
services:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
    - name: https
      port: 443
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 8443
    - name: http
      port: 80
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 8080
```

Creating several definitions work fine but the ports part always have a newline when starting the sequence.

template services.yaml

```
{{- $top := . -}}
{{- range $key, $val := .Values.services.ports -}}
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: {{ printf "%s-%s" ($.Values.fullnameOverride) ($val.name) }}
  labels:
    app: {{ printf "%s-%s" ($.Values.fullnameOverride) ($val.name) }}
spec:
  type: {{ $.Values.services.type }}
  ports:
  - {{ toYaml $val | trim | nindent 4 }}
  selector:
    app: {{ $.Values.fullnameOverride }}
---
{{- end }}
```

But when I execute the above template I get the following output:

```
---
# Source: arichnettools/templates/services.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: arichnettools-https
  labels:
    app: arichnettools-https
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
  -
    name: https
    port: 443
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8443
  selector:
    app: arichnettools
---
# Source: arichnettools/templates/services.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: arichnettools-http
  labels:
    app: arichnettools-http
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
  -
    name: http
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app: arichnettools
---
```

I do not know how to get rid of the newline after `ports:` I am not sure if that will give me an error during deployment, but it just drive me crazy. I have tried as well with `indent` but no luck so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This new line after `ports:` shouldn't cause any errors, but you can easily get rid of it with just one modification to your template.

Instead of:

```
ports:
  - {{ toYaml $val | trim | nindent 4 }}
```

Try to use:

```
  ports:
  - {{ toYaml $val | indent 4 | trim }}
```

We can see that after the modification it works as expected:

```
$ cat templates/services.yaml
{{- $top := . -}}
{{- range $key, $val := .Values.services.ports -}}
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: {{ printf "%s-%s" ($.Values.fullnameOverride) ($val.name) }}
  labels:
    app: {{ printf "%s-%s" ($.Values.fullnameOverride) ($val.name) }}
spec:
  type: {{ $.Values.services.type }}
  ports:
  - {{ toYaml $val | indent 4 | trim }}
  selector:
    app: {{ $.Values.fullnameOverride }}
---
{{- end }}

$ helm template test .
---
# Source: mychart/templates/services.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: svc-test-https
  labels:
    app: svc-test-https
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
  - name: https
    port: 443
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8443
  selector:
    app: svc-test
---
# Source: mychart/templates/services.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: svc-test-http
  labels:
    app: svc-test-http
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app: svc-test
```